# Is it possible to build binaries for different targets using CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm considering to use CMake for projects targeting a microcontroller. I found out how to create a toolchain file and invoke `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=Path/To/Toolchain.cmake` to make CMake do cross-compiling.

However most projects that I work on have also code that must be compiled for the host platform. These are often unit tests or other test tools, which share most part of their code with the binary that will run on the microcontroller. A rare case might be a project that even has two processors having a different instruction architectures, thus needing a host compiler and two different cross compilers.

I'd like to have one build that rules them all. Is it possible to have a construction that I only need to call `cmake /path/to/source && make`, or is the only solution having multiple 'root' `CMakeList.txt` files, each for every target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each cmake run will target one specific generator and thus one platform.

What you want can be achieved by having one hierarchy of CMakeLists files for each platform. You need to get to a point where doing a succession of `cmake .. && make` calls will build the whole project.

Then write a master CMakeLists that executes all of those separate build steps for you, e.g. through [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aExternalProject) or by using custom commands. Depending on the structure of your project it might make sense to have only the tools required for building being processed this way and add the sources for the actual project directly to the master CMakeLists instead.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried this and it works more or less, but feels not very subtile. One major problem I have now is that when you invoke the 'master' make after a change is made in one of the sub project, those changes will not be rebuild. You have to `cd` into the subproject build dir, and call `make` there yourself.

Comment: @Bart That is indeed a frustrating limitation. External projects are not supposed to change regularly, so there is no explicit support for this scenario (at least none that I know of).